# Angular drag and drop using transferArrayItem points to wrong index number upon filtering (working example)

Tags: angular, angular-material

I am trying to filter a list of items using the Drag Material CDK... all is working well when my list is not filtered, however when I filter it, and drag and drop, I get the wrong item (wrong index) on the drop, I created a working example, as you can see, filter by let's say "av" and drag avocado to drop area and you will get Carrot as the index is referring to the old data source, any ideas are appreciated,

here is a working example of the problem: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-agf3kv-wjxwdm?file=app/cdk-drag-drop-disabled-sorting-example.css

Sean

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use `itemsFiltered` as `cdkDopListData`.

```
<div
  cdkDropList
  [cdkDropListData]="itemsFiltered" <-- HERE
  class="example-list"
  cdkDropListSortingDisabled
  (cdkDropListDropped)="drop($event)">
  <div class="example-box" *ngFor="let item of itemsFiltered" cdkDrag>{{item}}</div>
</div>
```

[Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-agf3kv-ibgqm4?file=app%2Fcdk-drag-drop-disabled-sorting-example.html)

Comment: THANK YOU SO MUCH! Yep, figured it was something of that nature, didn't update the original list with the right array, TX AGAIN!!!!

Comment: You are welcome, it's always the basic stuff that gets us :D

Comment: I tried to convert to Table with no luck.. any ideas on that? https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-agf3kv-qhsmgp?file=app/cdk-drag-drop-disabled-sorting-example.css

Comment: Check the variables for the columns of each table

Comment: fixed the element.symbol. the issue is that the target does not accept the drop

Comment: really odd... simplified it to bare minimum with no luck: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-agf3kv-qhsmgp?file=app%2Fcdk-drag-drop-disabled-sorting-example.ts

Comment: [Edited] Here is a working prototype: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-9attms

Comment: You have to call `table.renderRows()` See here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53377450/reorder-mat-table-rows-with-angular-materials-drag-and-drop

Comment: This doesn't work though.
1) Filter the item, for example 'Tomatoes'
2) Drag and drop to the second list
3) Clear the filter
4) Observe that `Tomatoes` are still in the first list

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue and having a getter function to get `itemsFiltered` bugged on my end for the data. Note that I'm working with dynamic lists, so the user can choose how many drag & drop lists are available and which.

I solved my issue by just not displaying the card based on the filter, that way the index remained correct:

```html
   <div     cdkDropList 
            id="{{list.projectName}}" 
            [cdkDropListData]="list.products"
            class="list-droparea"
            (cdkDropListDropped)="drop($event, list)">
        <div    *ngFor="let product of list.products"
                class="card-dropable" 
                cdkDrag
<!--here-->     [class.item__hidden]="!product.productName.toLocaleLowerCase().includes(list.searchTerm.toLowerCase())"
                [class.item__moved]="product.originalProjectId !== list.id">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-12"><h6> {{product.productModelName}} </h6></div>
                <div class="col-12"><small class="m-0 secondary"> {{product.productName}}     </small></div>
                <div class="col-12" *ngIf="product.originalProjectId !== list.id">
                    <strong [innerHTML]="getProject(product.originalProjectId)"></strong>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

And in the styles i have `.item__hidden{ display:none }`

Answer (score 2):

Here a better solution

In `transferArrayItem` replace

```
event.previousIndex
```

with

```
event.previousContainer.data.indexOf(event.item.data)
```

Example :

```js
drop(event: CdkDragDrop<Way[]>) {
    if (event.previousContainer === event.container) {
      moveItemInArray(event.container.data, event.container.data.indexOf(event.item.data), event.currentIndex);
    } else {
      transferArrayItem(event.previousContainer.data,
        event.container.data,
        event.previousContainer.data.indexOf(event.item.data),
        event.currentIndex);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

be sure to call: 
`this.dtable.renderRows();`
as this will update the destination.